# Stripe Connect Account - return_url - Link back to Expo application

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I'm on-boarding users onto Stripe connect. My node server generates a temporary HTTPS URL so that customers can sign on. According to their docs I need to provide a URL for when they complete the application.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/account_links/create#create_account_link

I have an Expo application. The user will open up the URL in their browser. However when they complete their application I would like them to go back to Expo App. If I try to use `expo://MYAPP/` as the return_url, Stripe does not recognize the URL schema.

Does anyone have an idea how i can return the user back into my application after completing their on-boarding done via the browser?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone one out there who runs into this post, this is was my solution. Your app has to link to a website. I am using Expo, but this is the React code to generate the link.

```js
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';

  const openPage = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(
        `${url}?linkingUri=${Linking.createURL('/?')}`,
      );
      let redirectData;
      if (result.url) {
        redirectData = Linking.parse(result.url);
      }

      setstate({ result, redirectData });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

When you load the site, make sure to pass the URL that was generated from your backend

Backend code:

```js
stripe.accountLinks
    .create({
      type: 'account_onboarding',
      account: accountID,
      refresh_url: `https://website.com/refresh`,
      return_url: `https://website.com/return`,
    })
```

When the user has the site open, have a button that redirects to the stripe URL.This is how i thought it went first

App -> Stripe connect

instead you have to approach it like this

App -> Website -> Stripe connect

Comment: Thanks for this!  Did you ever figure out how to close the browser window after the user submits?

Comment: What @AnOldGuyandHisDog said - did you figure out how to get the return_url to trigger the callback url?